# Can't plot dates in graph with Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, graph

I'm trying to plot a graph dates vs. counts. This is my code:

```
trip_data['start_date'] = sorted(trip_data['start_date'], key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
data_count = pd.DataFrame(data=trip_data['start_date'].value_counts().sort_index())
data_count.rename(columns={'start_date' : 'count'}, inplace = True)
data_count.reset_index(inplace=True)
data_count.rename(columns={'index' : 'start_date'}, inplace = True)
data_count.plot()
```

And I get this graph:

[image]

So clearly the dates won't plot correctly, they just add up as int. I've tried a number of solutions I've found on Google and here on Stackoverflow, but none seems to work. The majority of them also had stripping dates as the main point, but as the code shows that has already been done. Plotting a hist graph also reverses the x and y axes, if that's useful. Any thoughts? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you looked through [the Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) to see if there is an example?

Comment: There are many ways to plot dates on the axes. If you have a problem with those you need to provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

An option you have is to change the x-axis labels. Assuming your plot's current x-axis is using the index of the dataframe, you can use this code:

```
labels = data_count['start_date'].tolist()
plt.xticks(data_count.index.values, labels, rotation='vertical')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read in your csv file, try the following for parsing dates:

```
custom_date_parser = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y")
data = pd.read_csv('name.csv', date_parser=custom_date_parser, index_col=0)
```

Then plots should use the correct dates on the x-axis.